# Calling arbitrary number of WS.url().get() in sequence

Tags: list, scala, asynchronous, future, serial-processing

I have a List[String] of URLs that I want to load and process (parse, store to database) in sequence.

I found only fixed-length examples, like:

```
    def readUrls = Action {
    implicit request => {
        implicit val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

        val url1 = "http://some-website.com"
        val url2 = "http://other-website.com"

        Async {
            for {
                result1 <- WS.url(url1).get()
                result2 <- WS.url(url2).get()
            } yield {
                Ok(result1.body + result2.body)
            }
        }
}
```

But instead of url1 and url2, I need to process this puppy:

```
val urls = List("http://some-website.com", "http://other-website.com")
```

Thanks a bunch for any tips and advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chain `Future`s together arbitrarily in sequence, `foldLeft` ought to do the job:

```
urls.foldLeft(Future.successful[String]("")){ case (left, nextUrl) =>
    left.flatMap{ aggregatedResult =>
        WS.url(nextUrl).get().map( newResult =>
            aggregatedResult + newResult.body
        )
    }
}
```

Since you're just combining the request bodies together, I gave the `foldLeft` an initial value of a `Future` empty `String`, which each step in the fold will then add on the next response body.

Comment: Wow, what a speed! Thank you very much - already tested it and it's working like a charm ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
def executeUrls(urls: List[String]): Future[String] = {
  urls.foldLeft(Future(""))((accumulator, url) => {
      accumulator.flatMap(acc => {
        WS.url(url).get().map(response => {
          acc + response.body
        })
      }
  })
}
```

This should be what you're looking for, note that it returns a new Future.

Edit: apparently LimbSoup was faster.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I appreciate it. Shame I can't mark two correct answers.